# Codeigniter pierde sesión

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Tengo el siguiente problema:

Tengo una app developer.powerby.co (pruebas) donde pido la validación de usuario

Al ingresar, intento crear un registro de un aspirante en el formulario que tengo allí, pero al guardar redirecciona al login y pierde la sesión. Dejo el código:

Login Controll:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Login extends CI_Controller 
{

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index()
{
    if($this->session->is_logued_in)
    {
        redirect(base_url().'dashboard');
    }
    else
    {
        $login = array(
            'title' => 'Powerby - Conviertete en un Aspirante',
            'name' => $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(),
            'hash' => $this->security->get_csrf_hash(),
            'script' => 'login.js'
        );

        $this->load->view('includes/header', $login);
        $this->load->view('login', $login);
        $this->load->view('includes/footer', $login);
    }
}

public function validate()
{
    $this->load->model('people_model', 'People', TRUE);

    $user = $this->input->post('_email');
    $password = $this->input->post('_password');

    $profile = $this->People->login($user);

    if($profile)
    {
        if (crypt($password, $this->session->_password) === $this->session->_password)
        {
            $this->session->set_userdata('is_logued_in', TRUE);
            $this->index();
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->unset_userdata('is_logued_in');
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error_login', 'Verifique su contraseña.');
            redirect(base_url().'login', 'refresh');
        }
    }
}

public function salir()
{
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect(base_url().'login', 'refresh');
}
}
```

**People Model:**

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class People_model extends CI_Model 
{

/*protected $id = NULL;
protected $name = NULL;
protected $last_name = NULL;
protected $user = NULL;
protected $password = NULL;*/

function __construct() 
{
    parent::__construct();
}

/*public function __get($property)
{
    if (property_exists($this, $property))
    {
        return $this->$property;
    }
}

public function __set($property, $value)
{
    if (property_exists($this, $property))
    {
        $this->$property = $value;
    }
    return $this;
}*/

public function login($user)
{
    $this->db->select('*')
             ->from('people p')
             ->join('user u', 'u._id_PPL = p._id')
             ->where('u._user', $user);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows() == 1)
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata($query->row_array());
        return $query->row();
    }
    else
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error_login', 'Verifique su usuario.');
        redirect(base_url().'login', 'refresh');
    }
}

public function create($params)
{
    $this->db->set($params);
    return $this->db->insert('people');
}
}
```

**Dashboard Controll:**

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller 
{

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index()
{
    if($this->session->is_logued_in)
    {
        $header = array(
            'title' => 'Powerby - Panel de control '.$this->session->_name.' '.$this->session->_last_name
        );

        $this->load->view('includes/header', $header);

        $this->load->helper('form');

        $dashboard = array(
            'name' => $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(),
            'hash' => $this->security->get_csrf_hash()
        );
        $this->load->view('dashboard', $dashboard);

        $modal = array(
            'icon' => 'sign out',
            'modal_title' => 'Cerrando Sesión!',
            'modal_description' => 'Estas a punto de cerrar tu sesión de usuario, estas seguro de querer salir ahora?'
        );
        $this->load->view('includes/modal', $modal);

        $footer = array(
            'script' => 'dashboard.js|people.js'
        );
        $this->load->view('includes/footer', $footer);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('sesion_cerrada', 'La sesión fue cerrada, ingrese de nuevo.');
        redirect(base_url().'login', 'refresh');
    }
}
}
```

En el Modelo People están los servicios tanto para login como para guardar una persona. Les dejo la configuración de la sesion en mi config:

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'pbytoken';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'pbycookie';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();

$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'pbysession';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'session';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```

Como notaron, uso la clase security para este propósito.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar con esto?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Me pasaba lo mismo y note que el error era muy raro, por alguna razon perdia la sesion cuando usaba nombres con el caracter "_", proba cambiando esto:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('is_logued_in', TRUE);
por esto:
$this->session->set_userdata('isloguedin', TRUE);
```

Lo mismo para todos tus nombres con ese caracter. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Es un bug muy común en `codeigniter`. Para que yo lo solucionara antes, hice dos cosas:

1. Modificar el `php.ini` de mi servidor para darle un valor de activo al parámetro [`session.auto_start`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start). Esto lo necesitamos en orden que las sesiones al pasar de un lugar a otro en el aplicativo sigan inicializadas.
2. Dentro de tu `config.php` ubica la línea parecida a `$config['cookie_domain']    = 'localhost';` Reemplaza el valor de `$config['cookie_domain']` al nombre de tu dominio. Si estás en localhost, déjalo como tal, si ya estás en productivo, especifica el host de tu dominio aquí. Si tu página es `www.ejemplo.com` tu línea debe de ser `$config['cookie_domain']    = 'www.ejemplo.com';`. Si por ejemplo estás en un subdominio como `subdominio.ejemplo.com` el valor debe de quedar como `$config['cookie_domain']   = 'subdominio.ejemplo.com';`. Puedes encontrar más información en el foro de inglés de lo que trabajamos [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783595/codeigniter-session-cookie-domain).

Por último, la respuesta que dio nuestro compañero Ivan Koop también puede ser factor de por qué podría fallar, pero en general, la problemática siempre viene desde  más arriba, por parte de configuraciones correctas del framework de codeigniter y como éste convive con el servidor.